# It is really possible to record stereo from WASAPI like Audacity does on ffmpeg or maybe can be implemented?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, recording

I'm using a windows 10 pc where isn't available the Stereo Mix or What you Hear option... it is not hidden or disable, is completely non existent.

Given I don't want to install some external filters to do it, I'm using for now Audacity that has the option for record the stereo loopback as you can see here: https://www.howtogeek.com/217348/how-to-record-the-sound-coming-from-your-pc-even-without-stereo-mix/

Can ffmpeg do this with wasapi recording? Bard says thing like:

```
ffmpeg -f wasapi -i audio=loopback:Speakers -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -y output.wav
```

but it doesn't work.

I've read that some of the developers also read this board so maybe they can help.

I recorded various screen sessions both on audio with audacity and capturing screen with gdigrab and now I'm syncing them manually but it's starting to get very time consuming do it manually.